# cs cart how to pass variables through tpl files

Tags: cs-cart

in the checkout page, I am trying to pass a variable through step 2 to step 3. I want to check the town of the user and do specific payments methods according to the town of the user.
I tried a lot, but couldn't see the variable. It always returns blank!

In the step 2, (this is the page with the address and everything about the user-client) I did this:

{assign var="town" value="$user_state"}

How can I pass this variable to step 3? (file name is payment_methods.tpl)

*I read something about smarty...
I tried {php} code...

Any help? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

ok I found a solution to my problem.
Inside the step_profile_fields.tpl file, I have done my calculations and capture this variable, for example:
{capture name="state_of_user"}{$ship}{/capture}

In step 4, I have included the previous tpl file (step_profile_fields.tpl)
and grab this value through:
$smarty.capture.**state_of_user**
For example I have this:
{include file=".." user=$smarty.capture.**state_of_user**}

if someone need more help. please let me know!